# Limiting SMS messages per user with node.js. (Twilio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, server-side

So I've been messing around with node.js and twilio these past couple of days. I managed to get it running and create a nice little system of keyword checks and responses. The problem is I need a way to prevent a conversation from going beyond X amount of exchanged messages. Anything that can get the user to stop messaging or get twilio to stop accepting them would be great.

I've looked into things like blocking their number, or even trying to activate the STOP keyword for them but nothing came up. The best I thought of was creating a counter of inbound and outbound messages and sending a final messaging stating "You've reached the conversation limit. You'll be charged X amount per every new message sent and received" to scare them off.I'm not really sure if that option is ethical or even legal.

I don't want to wake up one day and find that I owe $5000 in SMS fees because my numbers were spammed even after users have already gone through every possible dialogue option. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : I think I've found my answer so I'll post it here in case anyone else has the same thought. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181648-Is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-SMS-on-my-Twilio-phone-number-

Comment: This might be off-topic for the site, given that it concerns your budget, Twilio's pricing, and whether or not you're beyond the limits of a free trial. None of which have anything to do with *coding* a Twilio/node.js based solution.

Comment: @chb Well I was specifically looking for a coding solution. Mostly interested if they had anything in their API that I could utilize but possibly overlooked, but I'd understand how this could've come off as a billing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio billing is prepaid (for me), so i don't think you will **"owe $5000"**. They could burn thru your credit and if you are set up for auto top up, that could be an issue.

That being said there are different ways to keep on top of spending without coding.  I would recommend taking a look at the following:

1. [Account Triggers](https://www.twilio.com/console/usage/triggers/create) - Get notifications
2. [Projects](https://www.twilio.com/console/projects/summary) - Isolate your numbers/apps that are in production

#### Some Coding Ideas

I am guessing you are using a twilio number to bridge two users that gives anonymity.  What you proposed should be possible.

1. Use a function to query your logs and rate limit with your own logic
   [Docs: Usage Records](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records)
2. Use a database, record transactions, and query the data base with your own logic

**Note:** if the incoming message is generated by an incoming sms/mms, an incoming fee will be charged regardless of if the message is relayed or not.

**Additionally**, there are rate limiting npm modules available (I have not explored them). ex// [npm limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this specific question is off-topic. However, I'll state few things.

As of now, you can't control incoming messages. Twilio does that for you. For example, twilio charge you only for numbers validated as spam-free. You can get more information from their support agents.

From your side, you can try few other things.

1. Control the outgoing messages (For instance, detect spam, and do not send automatic replies if any)
2. Stick into a basic plan

For controlling the incoming load to your application, there is a library called `queuep`(npm install `queuep`). You can easily write the spam detection logic and avoid a load of messages. There are other benefits such as throttling and memoization.

But this does not guarantee that you are not charged for the load if any. That is because, charging happens even before the message is received by the NodeJs application. Only possible place to control this is through the twilio admin panel

Comment: A spam filter is probably the most I can do at this point unless twilio adds messaging limiters into their API. Thanks you, I'll definitely look into queuep and see if it helps the running costs of my programs.